# Wemos D1 Mini using RF with RCSwitch

Tags: rf

I’ve bought a RF transmitter and receiver on eBay and I’m trying to get my garage door codes with my Wemos D1 Mini.

[image: RF transmitter and receiver]

I’ve downloaded the RCSwitch library, hooked up the receiver to ground, 5v and data to pin D4.  Also flashed the sample receiver sketch.

The problem is that I don’t get anything on serial monitor... the Wemos board has an inbuilt led that flashes when I press my garage remote buttons, which means that pin DATA is sending a signal to the board, but I can’t see anything on serial monitor (Baud rates and serial connectivity is all good).

Tried other pins and didn’t get anything different.

Does anyone know how can I specify the pins with RCSwitch or have and idea of what is going on?

***UPDATE 1***
I’ve certified that transmitter is working and hooked properly using the Radiohead library.

[image: receiver and transmitter test]

***UPDATE 2***
The remote I have is so cheap that it is barely impossible to determine which chip it uses:

[image: chip of current remote]

Comment: get the neighbor's garage door codes too if it is possible :-)

Comment: Well, I can’t get even my garage door codes... 

Comment: why do you believe that you can receive your garage control codes with that device?

Comment: Actually, I don’t need the code, I need to clone the signal to open my garage using my Wemos

Comment: how about sharing your code?

Comment: There is no code to share. I was running the example from RCSwitch library

Comment: Would be interesting to share the code anyway, also the schema you're connecting your arduino to the RC or TX devices. I am connecting to D2 (pin #2, so INT0) as the sample requests.